# CSS: Changing only one specified color?

Tags: css, image, colors, color-picker

I am looking for a solution of this problem. I will have a lot of videos and images. I have to change the colors. But only the color of one part. When you look to the cars: it would be always the same one picture but the color would be changed by CSS. So I could use colors like magenta or cyan and then change them to the preferred color.

Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: One solution is to have all the images on the same place and just make the "top" image have the biggest `z-index`. Another is to use `canvas` and repaint the image.

Comment: Can you post the code that you have please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. What you'll need to do is change the car image so that it hasn't any color. You'll need to change the shading to a transparent white/ black PNG image.

The space on the outside needs to be a solid color, which would be the same as your websites background, for example white.

I couldn't find a good image, so I added a few extra lines of CSS. But I think you'll understand how you can achieve it.

Basically all you need to do is put your image in a wrapper. Change the background color of those wrappers to your needs. The (semi) transparency of the image will "color the car".

```css
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1em;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.icon img {
  max-width: 100px;
  display: block;
}
.red { background-color: red; }
.blue { background-color: blue; }
.yellow { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<div class="icon red"><img src="http://freeflaticons.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/square-copy-1412171043g4k8n.png" /></div>
<div class="icon blue"><img src="http://freeflaticons.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/square-copy-1412171043g4k8n.png" /></div>
<div class="icon yellow"><img src="http://freeflaticons.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/square-copy-1412171043g4k8n.png" /></div>
```